# Number of segments in SpatialLinesDataFrame

Tags: r, sp

After importing a spatial lines dataframe with `readOGR`, I would like to determine the number of line segments (nodes) in each line.  I cannot find a practical way to simply export the lengths as a vector.

`routes@lines` will get me to the line slots, but then how does one get the length of each one?

For example, in the sample data below, we see that the first line is composed of 93 segments, the second line composed of 170 segments, the third 91 segments, and so on.

In the end, I'd like a vector of 1657 numbers representing the length of line segments in the `SpatialLinesDataFrame`

Is there a quick solution?

```
> class(routes)
[1] "SpatialLinesDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
> str(routes)
Formal class 'SpatialLinesDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 4 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 1657 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ start_time: Factor w/ 1631 levels "2016/09/09 00:00:02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. ..$ duration  : int [1:1657] 786 1248 738 786 651 660 616 889 408 475 ...
  .. ..$ difftime  :Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:1657] 2 4 19 67 92 119 170 202 206 213 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
  ..@ lines      :List of 1657
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ Lines:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:93, 1:2] -79.9 -79.9 -79.9 -79.9 -79.9 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ ID   : chr "0"
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ Lines:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:170, 1:2] -79.9 -79.9 -79.9 -79.9 -79.9 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ ID   : chr "1"
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Lines' [package "sp"] with 2 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ Lines:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Line' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords: num [1:91, 1:2] -79.9 -79.9 -79.9 -79.9 -79.9 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ ID   : chr "2"
```

Comment: You are asking about *segments* but you refer to *coordinates*. Do you want the number of coordinates in each part?

Comment: I want the number of coordinate pairs in each part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method works

```
sapply( routes@lines, function (x) dim(x@Lines[[1]]@coords)[1] )
```

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot2` `fortify` is good for this. Once you have a table of all coordinates, identified by 'id' (row per SpatialDF object) and 'group' (parts per object), then you can group/by summarize.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
fortify(routes) %>% group_by(id, group) %>% 
 ## number of points per group
 summarize(npoint = n()) %>% 
 ## number of points per id
 summarize(npoint = sum(npoint))
```

If you really mean *segments* you could subtract from the point count first.

My pseudo code might be off the mark, but once you understand the fortify output it's easy to modify a summary to suit.